# How to json encode this data in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have the following code in my controller:

```
$regions = $this->signup_m->get_regions($country_id);
foreach ($regions as $key => $region) {
     echo "<option value='$key'>$region</option>";
}
```

It's being called by an ajax request. Instead of building out the html in the controller I rather return a json object back from which I can build out the dropdown options. How can I send this data in a json format?

I read about PHP's json_encode function and I am able to use it when I need to send back a single object but in this case I think I need to send back multiple objects (one for each dropdown option). So not sure how to go about it since it's all inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the php:

```
$regions = $this->signup_m->get_regions($country_id);
$jsonObj = array();
foreach ($regions as $key => $region) {
    $jsonObj[] = (object) array('value'=>$key, 'test'=>$region);
}
echo json_encode($jsonObj);
```

in the javascript you will receive a json object. if you are using jquery you're all set, just loop through the array. otherwise you'll have to parse/eval it and then loop through it

Comment: you don't need the (object) cast. json_encode will make an associative array a json object automatically

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using less space as follows:

```
$keysRegionsJSON = json_encode($this->signup_m->get_regions($country_id));
```

Then you would consume that as follows:

```
$keysRegions = json_decode($keysRegionsJSON);
foreach ($keysRegions as $key => $region) {
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $region . '</option>';
}
```

The same thing in plain JS:

```
for (key in keysRegionsJS) {
    document.write('<option value="' + key + '"> + keysRegionsJS[key] + '</option>';
}
```

Comment: why is the consumer in php? the question clearly has javascript the consumer

Comment: the question doesn't mention javascript, but now that you mention it that does make more sense. Adding JS to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without json_encode as follows

```
$json="{";
$count=0;
$regions = $this->signup_m->get_regions($country_id);
foreach ($regions as $key => $region) {
    if($count>0){$json.=",";}
    $json.="\"".$key."\":\"".$region."\"";
    $count++;
}
$json.="}";
echo $json;
```

and then you'll use a for in loop in your javascript to turn that back into the options

Comment: if your web host hasn't upgraded to PHP5

Comment: 1and1. They recently did add the ability to upgrade to 5, but I'd already gotten used to just doing it myself

Comment: @RobotWoods. You can find existing libraries that will provide a fall back function for PHP4. See http://techblog.willshouse.com/2009/06/12/using-json_encode-and-json_decode-in-php4/